# Split file text Angular

Tags: html, angular

I have this :

```
export class LeerArchivoComponent implements OnInit {
      private fileText;
      private nombre:String;
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
      }

      fileUpload(event){
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsText(event.srcElement.files[0]);
        var me = this;
        var nombre:String;
        reader.onload = function (){
          me.fileText = reader.result;     

        }         

}
```

And this one:

```
<input id="file-upload" 
   type="file" 
   accept=".txt" 
   (change)="fileUpload($event)">     
<textarea rows="4" cols="50">{{fileText}}</textarea>
```

Thats read a text file.
I have a text file like :

```
"u901_humext  ""2019-02-10 00:00""    99.97   99.97   99.97"

"u901_radpar   ""2019-02-10 15:40""    1002.9  1068.4  1034.3943396226"
```

The problem is that i want to split it by spaces, " and "".
How can i do that?
Thanks.
Im using Angular.

Answer (score 0):

Since parsing csvs can be quite problematic at times.
Are they using spaces or tabs. does the file contain text delimiters or not.
Are there any special formatting scenarios you need to take into account.

I would probably use a library to not reinvent the wheel.

https://github.com/okfn/csv.js/

It takes a blob as an input, so the file you uploaded you can simply pipe into it.

and you get this nice object back

```
{
  // an array of arrays - one array each row in the CSV
  // (excluding header row - i.e. first row)
  records: [ [...], [...], ... ],
  // list of fields
  fields: [ 'field-name-1', 'field-name-2', ... ],
  metadata: { may be some metadata e.g. file name }
}
```

Could that be your solution?

Comment: I have a .txt file not a .csv file

Comment: that doesn't matter. the format of the file is called CSV or TSV (comma separated value). the above package will work for you. But if you want to do it manually, I would start to check that reader.result is of type string.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .split() 
string.split([separator])  the separator specifies the character to use for separating the string.